# Scheduling MSAccess DB VBA module automatically for every 10 minutes

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a module created "Sub Split()" in MSAccess DB VBA and I want to schedule this module to execute automatically after every 10 minutes . I did check out the code which says Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "Split" but its throwing an error . Is it that this function is applicable only in Excel and not in Access and If I want the same function in Access is there any way to do it?

Comment: please include your code

Comment: I have not written any code for scheduling as I am not aware as to how to do it.

Comment: Use a Form's[Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-timer-event-access) event. Note you should set `TimerInterval` to 600000 Miliseconds/

Answer (score 0):

Create a form to b opened in the background, and in it's code section paste this code:

```
Sub Form_Load() 
    Me.TimerInterval = 600000 
End Sub 

Sub Form_Timer() 
    Split
End Sub
```

Open the Form, and `Split` will run every 10 minutes.

Comment: I did Use this but its not doing anything. Its still the same.

Comment: Before you set the timer to 10 minutes, you might want to have it run every 10 seconds (`Me.TimerInterval = 1000 * 10`). That way, you're not waiting 10 minutes to test your code. Also, as a point of clarification: You can't schedule a __module__ to run every so often, but only a sub-routine or function within that module. What does your `Split` sub do?

Comment: Hi Zack, My split function splits the multivalued data which is stored in single column into different rows.

Comment: That might be a bigger issue than your timer: You shouldn't be storing multi-valued data in a single field in Access, or any other database. Could you include a screenshot of your form, so we can maybe have an idea of what you're expecting to do?